# unable to parse "" as integer[FC]

Tags: android, string, integer

I have this code to control if a EditTextPreference is null or not:

```
    case R.id.prochain_vidange:
                settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                String choix_huile = settings.getString("listPref_huile_moteur", "0");
                km = settings.getString("km", "");
                Log.d("TAG",km);
               int x= Integer.valueOf(km);
               if (km != "")
{
               if (Integer.valueOf(choix_huile) == 0) {
    ............
```

The problem is in this line:

```
int x= Integer.valueOf(km);
```

What could be the problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give [Integer.valueOf(String s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) a string that is not a valid number, it throws a NumberFormatException. Change the default value to 0:

```
km = settings.getString("km", "0");
```

Alternatively, you can catch the exception, and set `x` to `0`:

```
km = settings.getString("km", "");
int x;
try {
    x = Integer.valueOf(km);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah good point, but then he can save the value as Integer in the first place.

Comment: @Michele - that's a good point, usually I intend to keep the code as close as possible to the original, but you're probably right in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Integer.valueOf trys to make a new Integer with .parseInteger(String s), "" cant be parsed to a valid number so you get a NumberFormatException

You can catch it with a try catch block or you can simply dont try to make a Integer with the String "".

before:

```
int x= Integer.valueOf(km);
if (km != "") {
```

after:

```
if (km != "") {
int x= Integer.valueOf(km);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.valueOf(km)` can throw an exception if the the `km` string is not able to be parsed as an integer.

However, wrapping it in a `try { } catch()` block is not an approach I would recommend.

The whole purpose of having a default value on the [`getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is that there can be a default value to fall back on if the preference doesn't exist. So the better way to solve this is to modify your `settings.getString(...)` call to be like this:

```
 km = settings.getString("km", "0");
```

Then your subsequent call to `Integer.valueOf(km)` will not have a blank to fail upon.

Is the input string coming from a blank text field where the user can enter any value?  If so, it's at that point that you can validate the value that the user entered. By validating the input early on, you won't need to scatter the checking/validating mechanism to other areas of your code.